# Numbers 19:11He that toucheth the dead body of any man shall be unclean seven days

Tags: numbers

Why unclean for seven days?

11He that toucheth the dead body of any man shall be unclean seven days.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that 7 days is indicative of the first creation. The eighth day is the day of resurrection - a new creation. The dead body is unclean until full and final redemption in resurrection.

The question is very brief and my answer is also brief. I could quote many texts in support but I really do not think it is necessary when such a broad scope is being viewed across the whole of scripture.

Jesus arose on the third day after his death. He also arose on the eighth day, that is to say the first day of a new week, after the sabbath was past.